# What is the status of the Child Tax Credit for 2013?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-credit

There have been many tax changes in the US recently, including the increase of the payroll tax.  However, I haven't heard about the significant child tax credit.  Will the child tax credit stay at its 2012 amount or be phased out?

Comment: I checked [the IRS page](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/Child-Tax-Credit), but I didn't see anything about 2013.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extended for five years. I wrote an article [Over The Cliff and Back](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/over-the-cliff-and-back-again/), in which I highlight the 2013 changes agreed to in Washington New Years evening. It remains at $1000 per child, but same as in prior years, phases out based on income.

The details of [H.R. 8, the American Taxpayer Relief Act (ATRA) of 2012](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/BILLS-112hr8eas/pdf/BILLS-112hr8eas.pdf), runs a full 157 pages. As a PDF, it's friendly to searching on specific words to find what you seek.

Comment: Surprisingly the act is actually readable and relatively easy to understand if you know what you're looking for. I'm not used to that with legalese.